# How do I sync a Datel 270 wheel with an Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I have lost the manual and cannot work out how to sync my [Datel 270 wheel](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Datel-Power-Racer-Wireless-Racing/dp/B005FWY9N2) with my Xbox 360. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was an [issue with an update](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/7/p/274017/1436778.aspx) which caused issues with Datel 270 racing wheels when trying to connect them to the Xbox 360 console.

If this problem is still outstanding you could try [contacting Datal Customer Support](http://www.datelcustomerservice.com/). There doesn't appear to be a manual online on their website for the Datal 270 wheel but they do answer queries reported via email.